# Finding the resonant frequency of a rectangular resonator filled with a magnetic material

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, field-theory, resonance, waveguide

The prompt is to find the resonant frequency $f_r$ of a rectangular resonator which is filled with a magnetic material rather than standard air or vacuum. I'm confused as how the resonance frequency changes when its filled with a magnetic material.

Noting that the walls are PEC.
TM mode is $TM_{110}$
$$\epsilon_r = 1 \ \mu_r = 1 \ \sigma = 0 s/m $$
$$ a = b = Xmm \ c = Ymm \ (X \&Y) > 0$$

My approach:
$$ 
f_{110} = \frac{c}{2\pi} \sqrt{ \bigl(\frac{ \pi}{a}\bigr)^2 + \bigl(\frac{\pi}{b}\bigr)^2} $$
$$ f_{110} = \frac{1}{v.2 \pi}\sqrt{ \bigl(\frac{ \pi}{a}\bigr)^2 + \bigl(\frac{\pi}{b}\bigr)^2} $$

$$ f_{110} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\epsilon\epsilon_r. \mu \mu_r }}\sqrt{ \bigl(\frac{ \pi}{a}\bigr)^2 + \bigl(\frac{\pi}{b}\bigr)^2} $$

Assuming the speed of light is lesser in a magentic medium.

source : https://www.ee.iitb.ac.in/uma/~rkashyap/ee614rep.pdf - eqn(20)

Answer (score 0):

Your answer seems to be correct. The resonant frequencies depend on the speed $v$ of the electromagnetic wave in the medium inside the resonator $$v=\frac {c}{\sqrt{\epsilon_r \mu_r}}$$ so that you can get the resonant frequencies for a $\mu_r \neq 1$ and $\epsilon_r=1$ by substituting $c$ by $v$ in the relevant formulas as long as you have a linear paramagnetic ($\mu \gt 1$) or diamagnetic ($\mu \lt 1$) medium. Ferromagnetic materials can, in general, not be considered to be linear.